# How to manage a dashboard displaying resources production/consumption?

Tags: web-app, grid, dashboard

Let me explain the context. The user has a list of **Factories**. Each Factory produce 1 to 5 **Resources**. For producing a resource, the factory consume 1 to 3 resources.

I need to give an overview of all the resources produced and consumed for a selected factory.

I don't known how to properly manage it. I thought about a production grid with a sub-grid for consumption, but I don't find it very clear... See the rough wireframe below:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhB94K.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Could you please help me to make a clear and understandable overview for this production/consumption dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid sounds like the safest thing to do. What you have there is quite fine and I have seen it in a lot of applications, so I won't give you suggestions for that.

I will instead provide you with some more daring alternatives that cross into the realm of data visualization.

The data you have there involves **factories**, **products** and **resources**. I don't know if two factories produce the same product or if two products use the same resource, or to be more specific, if the relationships map to a tree or a graph.

So I will provide you a solution for each case:

1. Sunburst chart

   You can place the factories in the center, the products in the middle layer and the resources on the outside. This maps very well for a tree-like data structure, but can work very well for a graph, by coloring the shared products/resources with consistent colors.

   [image]
2. Flow diagram (Sankey Diagram)

   You can place the factories to the left, the products in the middle and the resources to the right. This one works for a graph-like data structure.

   [image]

They are both quantitative representations and this means you can get a sense of the data just by looking at the screen, instead of comparing numbers.

Another advantage is the interactivity both support : highlighting, filtering, sorting.

There is software support for both of them, if you are interested, I can sugest you some libraries as well.