# Should I display a "plus" in front of a production number?

Tags: numbers, symbols

I have a grid displaying stocks and production of resources (related to [my previous question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/81638/how-to-manage-a-dashboard-displaying-resources-production-consumption)).

Should I display a plus symbol (+) in front of the production number when it's positive?
Or do you think displaying the number is enough and the plus symbol is unnecessary?

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on whether its an **incremental value** or **total value**. For example, consider the StackExchange website. When you get reps, you see +10 as notification whereas there's no (+) in front of your total reputation because it's a total value. If the production of resources is changing with time, I would recommend using (+) provided you're showing the total value somewhere in the UI. In your UI, if the stock value = total value, you can use (+) to show increment in production.